# Liferay MinifierUtil produces syntax errors

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, liferay, minify

Liferay MinifierUtil produces syntax errors when there is any "debugger" placed in JavaScript code

> MinifierUtil:111] 39: 13: identifier is a reserved word
>   20:27:17,721 ERROR [http-apr-8080-exec-32][MinifierUtil:111] 61: 12: identifier is a reserved word
>   20:27:17,722 ERROR [http-apr-8080-exec-32][MinifierUtil:111] 365: 12: identifier is a reserved word
>   20:27:17,722 ERROR [http-apr-8080-exec-32][MinifierUtil:111] 454: 12: identifier is a reserved word
>   20:27:17,723 ERROR [http-apr-8080-exec-32][MinifierUtil:111] 1: 0: Compilation produced 4 syntax errors.
>   20:27:17,723 ERROR [http-apr-8080-exec-32][MinifierUtil:88] JavaScript Minifier failed for___var redirect = " .... (more jsp code with debugger placed in script)

It gives random behaviour some times JSP is loaded sucessfully and some times it crashes, I am not sure whether this error is crashing my JSP code or not. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the JSP source?

The log is saying that you has used the word 'identifier' that is a reserved word, and that is causing the fail.

Comment: also: what Liferay version are you talking about?

Comment: Liferay version 6.2, @Olaf

Comment: Sorry can't show JSP source I just have the server logs @Carlos